# How Does C# Handle Locking On A Dictionary Item?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary

I was working on some pathfinding code for a game in C# (.NET 3.5) and I added parallelism of the pathfinding to the game to make it faster. The AI agents must "register" with the pathfinding system and are provided a `id` in return. A dictionary `agentMap` stores information for a AI agent to do with it's pathfinding calls (the last start point, end point and path calculated for the last pathfinding call).

When I start a parallel pathfinding search the first thing the thread does is call `lock(agentMap[id])`. The thing is that the game loop also accesses `agentMap[id]` when updating where the agent wants to go. Somehow, the game hasn't frozen up (as far as I can tell).

As I understand it, `agentMap[id]` locks on the item referred to by the key `id` so when the game loop tries to access that item the game loop should be blocked. Is there some special behaviour of locking on a dictionary item (or am I just lucky not to have problems)?

Code for parallel pathfinding thread:

```
/*
    C# will nicely this function in a parallel thread for me
*/
void getBasicPathParallelized (object id)
{
    lock (agentMap [id]) {
        try {
            /* get path */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* error handling */
        }
    }
}
```

Starting the pathfinding thread:

```
agentMap [caller].pathfindingThread = new Thread (this.getBasicPathParallelized);
agentMap [caller].pathfindingThread.Start (caller);
```

The game loop code that manipulates the `agentMap [id]` items is too long to share in full but here is a section to show how the game loop uses the items of the dictionary:

```
agentMap [id].openList = new NodeList<PathNode> ();
agentMap [id].destination = destination;
agentMap [id].start = start;
agentMap [id].flags = flags;
++agentMap [id].pathSearchID;
agentMap [id].startTriangle = startTriangle;
agentMap [id].destinationTriangle = destinationTriangle;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `agentMap` is a generic `Dictionary<x,y>`, not `ConcurrentDictionary<x,y>`, correct?

Comment: @CrescentFresh Note that it doesn't affect the question asked, although it would affect how you'd go about writing the code correctly.

Comment: `(or am I just lucky not to have problems)?` If you are using `Dictionary<x,y>` then you are just lucky. Reading from `Dictionary` is not thread-safe if another thread is writing to it - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_10 .

Comment: With your code snippet down the bottom, if they are indeed sequential lines of code, have a think through what would happen if two threads execute those lines at roughly the same time. _For example, it is possible that `agentMap [id].startTriangle` ends up with the value from a different thread than `agentMap [id].destinationTriangle`._

Comment: This looks very, very wrong. What shared resource are you manipulating inside the lock? Also, if you are trying to parallelize a long-running operation then **locking the key data structure is the last thing you want to do**.  That will serialize the operation!

Comment: It is just a dictionary
I wanted to stop a pathfinding thread from giving the AI the path if the AI changed where it wanted to go, but at that late stage things got rushed and illogical decisions were made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so when the game loop tries to access that item the game loop should be blocked

No.  If the game loop tries to *lock* on the item, it'll be blocked.  If it tries to access the item then it will just access the item.  If you want it to block, it needs to `lock` around access to it.  Because you're accessing a shared object without proper synchronization, all sorts of bad things can happen.

Note that mutating an object from multiple places like this, and having a widely accessible object being synchronized on, are both bad ideas.  This object should almost certainly be immutable, and changes to the dictionary holding it should be properly synchronized through a single type responsible for ensuring properly synchronized access, possibly by using a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a `Dictionary`.

Comment: That explains it perfectly. I stupidly forgot to have the game loop thread try and acquire a lock on the dictionary. Thanks!